# Need to calculate total distance traveled in a 2D random walk

Tags: random-process

```
Part1
s = {0., 0.};
path = Table[s += RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, 2], {100}];
ListLinePlot[path, ImageSize -> Small]
path
```

This part of the code generates 100 xy coordinates or steps and I need a code to calculate total distance with a DO loop

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is this a homework question? If so, please add the "homework" tag and update your post with the ideas and/or code you have used to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[1]
s = 0; path = Table[s += RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, 2], {100}];
```

You can use [`ArcLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html) or [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html):

```
ArcLength[Line@path]
```

> 36.96705

```
RegionMeasure[Line@path]
```

> 36.96705

Answer (score 2):

With

```
path = Accumulate@Prepend[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {100, 2}], {0, 0}];
```

here are a couple of possibilities:

```
EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[path, 2, 1] // Total
BlockMap[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, path, 2, 1] // Total
```